# Oracle Error ORA-19502: write error on file

Tags: oracle

I’m creating a tablespace in oracle using this code:

```
Create BIGFILE tablespace SPC_X
    Datafile 'SPC_X.dbf'
      size 200M
      AUTOEXTEND ON NEXT 50M 
  ONLINE;
```

Up to now, I have created couple of tablespaces, without any problem. Today I have created 5 tablespaces (500 M) and dropped them all. Right now I am facing this error after execution code, mentioned above:

```
SQL-Error: ORA-19502: write error on file " SPC_X.dbf", block number 11136 (block size=8192)
ORA-27072: File I/O error
Additional information: 4
Additional information: 11136
Additional information: 708608
19502. 00000 -  "write error on file \"%s\", blockno %s (blocksize=%s)"
*Cause:    write error on output file
*Action:   check the file
```

Following Information could be helpful:

- It was successfully executing up to now.
- I am SA on my data base.
- I have enough place
- size should be at least 200 M
- I have googled more than 1,5 hours, no success :(

Can someone please help me on this issue? Thanks :)

--

update1: Could it be that my drop statement, which I have used to drop old tablespases, was not complete?

```
 DROP TABLESPACE SPC_A 
   INCLUDING CONTENTS 
      CASCADE CONSTRAINTS;
```

--

update2: I have tried this code without any success:

```
ALTER DATABASE DATAFILE 'SPC_A' OFFLINE DROP;
```

This code cannot works out, since the tablespace has been already deleted

```
ALTER TABLESPACE example DROP DATAFILE 'SPC_A';
```

Comment: Time to buy a new harddisk? You can try this: shut down Oracle, then try to copy SPC_X.dbf to some other location. If the `copy` resp. `cp` command whines about not being able to read the file, then your harddisk (or at least your file system) is broken.

Comment: @ammoQ : Thanks for your answer.Today I have created 5 tablespaces (500 M) successfully and dropped them all. Now I want create 1 tablespace again and am facing this error. I do not have any access to the servers and I cannot imagine, that the servers are getting problem.

Comment: Well, block 11136 is in the middle of the file, and 200M is not exactly a size that scratches Oracle's limits (or the limits of any file system, for the matter), so my first and only idea is: Maybe Oracle is right and there *is* a file I/O error?

Comment: Could it be that my drop statement, which I have used to drop old tablespases, was not complete?

Comment: missing is the and datafiles clause. Your datafiles have not been dropped from the fs.

Comment: @ik_zelf: I'm not sure, but I think, this could be the reason. However I didn't find any solution to drop the datafiles after delete the tablespace?

Comment: Once the tablespace is dropped, the datafiles are no longer relevant for oracle. You can just as well delete them using the OS commands.

Comment: @ammoQ: Is there any possibility to do it via oracle?

Comment: Correct. The issue was here missed „and datafiles“ and limited disc space. Solution: Ask Administrator to delete the data files. After deleting data files, I was able to create new tablespaces.@ik_zelk and @ammoQ Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally you drop a tablespace using

```
drop tablespace x including contents and datafiles;
```

this prevents the need to use OS commands to drop the datafiles from the filesystem and is a bit more secure than using OS commands deleting the unneeded files since manually, a typo is easier done than fixed.

In your situation, first cleanup the files from the OS. I assume the errors you get are when you try to re-create the tablespace using the same datafile[s].

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I do not have any direkt access to servers to use os command. however just requested the admin to do it. will let you know the result, once done. Do you know any possibility to do this via oracle?

Comment: You could try with utl_file.fremove as written in the docs: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/u_file.htm#i1003602

Comment: Thanks for your help. After deleting files using OS I was able to create new one. I didn't try utl_file.fremove.

Comment: @ik_zelf, I used exactly the same command but end up with the same error. Also verified on the OS if there is any file existing and None. Not sure if I have to delete any other files.